# VBA Application/object defined error when outputting array to .Cell declared range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, transpose

I have an issue where I get the 'application-defined or object defined error' when trying to output an array into a range.

```
 Worksheets("Log").Range(.Cells(MnthCount + 4, 6), .Cells(MnthCount + 4, MnthDayCount + 5)) = FrstLtr
```

That is the code, the array `FrstLtr` is 31 values in length. `MnthCount` is 2, `MnthDayCount` is 31. There should be enough space in the range to output the array? What is the issue here?

Comment: Please show us the code before this line. Are you using a `With`-statement? If not `.Cells` wouldn't "know" where it belongs ... Furthermore it is best practice to reference the workbook as well - to be on the safe side in case there are multiple workbooks open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Array Values to Worksheet

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
With Worksheets("Log")
    .Range(.Cells(MnthCount + 4, 6), _
        .Cells(MnthCount + 4, MnthDayCount + 5)).Value = FrstLtr
End With
```

**Understand This**

```vb
Dim cCount As Long
cCount = (MnthDayCount + 5) - (6) + (1) ' 5 - 6 + 1 = 0
cCount = MnthDayCount
```

**The Resize Connection**

```vb
Worksheets("Log").Cells(MnthCount + 4, 6).Resize(, MnthDayCount).Value = FrstLtr
Worksheets("Log").Cells(MnthCount + 4, 6).Resize(, cCount).Value = FrstLtr
```

**The Array Resize**

```vb
With Worksheets("Log").Cells(MnthCount + 4, 6)
    .Resize(, UBound(FstrLtr) + 1).Value = FrstLtr ' 1D zero-based
    .Resize(, UBound(FstrLtr)).Value = FrstLtr ' 1D one-based
    .Resize(, UBound(FstrLtr, 2) + 1).Value = FrstLtr ' 2D zero-based
    .Resize(, UBound(FstrLtr, 2)).Value = FrstLtr ' 2D one-based
End With
```

**A Common Scenario**

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Log")

With dws.Cells(MnthCount + 4, 6)
    .Resize(, cCount).Value = FrstLtr
End With
```